# sql search query in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to make a database search in my app where the user would choose the column and enter the search word and the result would come up in a dataviewgrid.
This is the code i've been working on, the problem is that nothing comes up and i'm pretty sure there are entries in the database. EDIT : it's a windows form application

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; database = Clients; Integrated Security = SSPI");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * From dbo.Tclients WHERE @choice = @input", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@choice", comboBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", textBox1.Text);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Does `Tclients` table contain `choice` column ? Which column you are going to filter ?

Comment: You cannot use a parameter to express the name of a column or a table name.

Comment: i didn't know that you can't do that, o well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a parameter to express the name of a column.
You should populate your combobox with the column names and set its `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList` (do not allow your user to type the name of the column) and then build your query

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cmdText = "SELECT * From dbo.Tclients WHERE " + comboBox1.Text + " = @input";
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(....))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@input", textBox1.Text);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is open for Sql Injection ! Just write column name !

Comment: I have specified that the column names should be added to the combobox and the DropDownStyle should be set to DropDownList. No edit possible with this style

Comment: this worked as i wanted it to be, thank you so much for your help

Comment: one more question @Steve what should i check for "if (....)" to know if it found the user or not ?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to bind the grid view with datasource
add this after data source

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: DataGridView (or better a WinForm app) doesn't need the DataBind call

Comment: it gives me an error after adding dataGridView1.DataBind();

Comment: Can you confirm its an ASP.NET application?
What is the error msg?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void bunifuThinButton21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\albasheer\Desktop\games\my_school\my_school\school.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "select name,id,stage,age,cost from STUDENT where   stage like '%" + bunifuCustomLabel1.Text + "%' and name like '%" + bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text + "%'";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);



        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        var dt = from t in table.AsEnumerable()
                 select new
                 {
                     id = t.Field<int>("id"),
                     Name = t.Field<string>("name"),
                    

                 };

        bunifuCustomDataGrid1.DataSource = dt.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31886236)